# Creating PDF using TCPDF and a specific div as the content

Tags: php, javascript, html, tcpdf

I am trying to create a receipt for a web application by turning the receipt from the HTML code into a PDF so that it can be downloaded upon completion of the application. I have tried to send the code to a PHP file by assigning the contents of the targeted div to a hidden input field within a form. Upon pressing the button at the end, the js function below is executed onclick, as well as the PHP file:

```
function print() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("receipt").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("hiddenhtml").value = elem;
}
```

Here is a rough outline of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="htmlpdf.php" target="_blank">
    <div id="receipt">
        ------- CONTENT THAT I WANT IN THE PDF ----------
    </div>
    <input type="submit" onclick="print()" value="Print"/>
    <input id="hiddenhtml" type="hidden" value=""/>
</form>
```

Where hiddenhtml is a hidden input field. Upon pressing the print button, the contents of the receipt div are added to the value of the hidden input field. I then try to pass this value as follows:

```
$html = $_POST['hiddenhtml'];
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

To use it in the writeHTML function. However, a blank PDF file is returned. I was wondering wether I can pass the contents of the targeted div as a parameter in the writeHTML method. The div has no external styling, and contains all compliant tags per the documentation.

Comment: are you sure that hidden field is being populated? did you check `var_dump($_POST)` to see if things are coming across correctly?

Comment: @MarcB I have checked, and yes, it is being populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a page to the document to render your html in and then you need to actually output your page. See the [example pdf page](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps). Your code should look like this:-

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('P');
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output();
```

I did some further testing and created this code:-

```
if(isset($_POST['hidden'])){
    $pdf = new TCPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage('P');
    $html = $_POST['hidden'];
    $pdf->writeHTML($html);
    $pdf->Output();
}
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input name="hidden" type="hidden" value="
        <div>
            <h1>Receipt</h1>
            <p>Some stuff</p>
            <p>More stuff</p>
        </div>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Which, on submition, gave me this output:-

[image]

As you can see, a nice pdf page with my html rendered into it.

I would suggest you reduce your code to something as simple as this to aid trouble shooting. Once you have that working, then you can add complexity.

Comment: I've done so, I get a blank page though because the code that I post to the html variable doesn't work as input for some reason

Comment: @DavisHunt Could you post an example of the html that should go into the pdf?

Comment: Example is above, just a bunch of formatted divs and text. All the styling is done inline, and there is no need for them to access an external styling sheet

Comment: What you are doing works correctly, but do you have any idea why when I create an _external_ php file, the isset conditional returns false?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your actual code. Could you provide a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) of it if its too much to post into your question?

Comment: @vascowhite could i ask about file include ? I have download #tcpdf_6_2_8.zip and i include tcpdf_include.php and tcpdf_config_alt.php  but still now found class TCPDF();

Comment: @skjulikaka If you have a new question to ask then please [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Comments are not the place to deal with a new question.

Comment: Don't know why my account can't ask question, how I can re ask it back ?